# Smalltalk: Setting value of a variable to object

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I have a (probably) very simple question regarding SmallTalk that I am not able to solve for few hours.

So, I am trying to create a simple app for managing students and exams - therefore I have classes Student (attributes: name, surname) and Exam (attributes: date, student, mark). Moreover, I have 2 datasets in GUI to show students (DatasetStudents) and exams (DatasetExams).

What I'm trying to do with following method is create a new exam when there is a student selected in the dataset. Then I try to set the selected student object as a value of exam's attribute student. However, the problem occurs on the `ex student: selected.` line. When I try `ex student: selected name.` to set value to selected student's name, which is string, it works like charm.

Is there any way how to assign whole object to variable?

```
newExam
    | selected ex |
    selected := DatasetStudents selection.

    selected isNil
        ifTrue: [^Dialog warn: ‘Select student before adding exam!’]
        ifFalse : [ nil ].

    ex := Exam new.
    ex student: selected.

    DatasetExams list add: ex.
```

What I'm trying to achieve overall is to automatically show relevant exams in second dataset for a student selected in first dataset, but I'm currently stuck at assigning students to exams...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What dialect and version of Smalltalk (note capitalization) are you using? The problem is not with setting the value of a variable to an object (which works fine since Smalltalk supports dynamic typing and a String is also an object), but appears later. I suspect that something in the remaining code expects a String (perhaps when printing?). You might try adding a `#'printOn:'` method to Student to see if that helps.

Comment: Seems like the problem was related to the dataset. Thanks to your insight, I went through the dataset properties thoroughly and finally found Column Type field hidden at the bottom of one tab. Hopefully, that was the issue.

Comment: Turns out that was not the problem, as for some reason, it works even when I deleted the column student from dataset exams. 

It was probably some issue with my image. I'm using VisualWorks 9.2.